# Get text field value onkeyup vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Without using v-model, how to retrieve text field's value when typing? If possible without using any methods.

```
<input type="text" class="form-field"
    v-on:keyup="data.sample = this.target.value">
```

I used

- this.value
- this.target.value
- e.target.value

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The solution is:

```
<input type="text" v-on:keyup="this.$data.name = $event.target.value">
```

From [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on):

> When listening to native DOM events, the method receives the native event as the only argument. If using **inline** statement, the statement has access to the special **$event** property: v-on:click="handle('ok', $event)"

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6387txur/)

Comment: Thanks. I have been on the documentation page. But because there is no concrete example, it's easy to read "over" it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle any key with Vuejs is like this :

`<input type="text" @keyup.stop.native="handleInput($event)">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="search-bg" placeholder="Search" v-model="search" @keyup="searchData"/>
```

Comment: thank you for the contribution -- can you add an explanation of what your code does to help future readers